# PHP Syntax error T_Return

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I am getting a T_Return syntax error on the below code.. any ideas?

```
function wp_support_create_feature( $post ) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE' && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post;

  if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post ) )
    return $post

  $first = get_children( array(
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'posts_per_page' => (int)1,
        ), ARRAY_A
   );
  set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $first[0]['ID'] );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_support_create_feature' );
```

Comment: Full error and line?  `ARRAY_A` = what?  Second `return` is missing a semi-colon;

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE' && DOING_AUTOSAVE ))
                                                 ^
```

You missed a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Well, yeah. Missing semi-colons and mis-defined arrays. But hey, he asked for the T_RETURN syntax error.

Comment: actually if there are other mistakes please let me know.. the code from Pedro del Sol is error free...

Comment: Pedro posted a completely error free code. He corrected additional mistakes as well. :)

Comment: No, it's not either. It also mingles the constant probing into the defined(). It's syntactically correct, but certainly won't accomplish the intended purpose.

Comment: mario you are right... the function does not complete the intended person after testing the corrected code from Pedro del sor..

Answer (score 2):

```
function wp_support_create_feature( $post ) {
   if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE' && DOING_AUTOSAVE )) // closing parens
   return $post;

   if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post ) )
   return $post; // semi-colon

$first = get_children( array(
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'posts_per_page' => (int)1,
    ), ARRAY_A
);
set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $first[0]['ID'] );

} add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_support_create_feature' );
```

Comment: update: syntax is correct but doesnt achieve what's needed.. (automatically add a featured image when publishing a post based on the first image inside the gallery of the post)

Comment: fixing the semantic errors have been left as an exercise for the reader...